# dataframe difference between consecutive row within group and creating string stating the same

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Dataframe:

```
col1  col_entity col2
a        a1       50
b        b1       40
a        a2       40
a        a3       30
b        b2       20
a        a4       20
b        b3       30
b        b4       50
```

I need to group them based on col1 and sort them highest to lowest based on col2 for each group
and find difference between consecutive row and then create column for different groups for string statement.
dateframe:

```
col1  col_entity col2   diff   col_statement
a        a1       50     10     difference between a1 and a2 is 10
b        a2       40     10     difference between a2 and a3 is 10
a        a3       30     10     difference between a3 and a4 is 10
a        a4       20     nan    **will drop this row**
b        b1       40     10     difference between b1 and b4 is 10
a        b4       50     10     difference between b4 and b3 is 10
b        b3       30     10     difference between b3 and b2 is 10
b        b2       20     nan    **will drop this row**
```

Please help me on this
Thanks in advance

Comment: did I answer your question? Kindly click the checkmark next to my solution if I have answered it. Also, please upvote if helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do a couple of np.where statemtents:

1. Use `diff().abs()` to get the absolute difference between one row and the row below with `.shift()`.
2. Return `NaN` for the `.dif()` if the extracted alphabetic characters do not match between one row and the next.
3. In the `col_statement` column build a string based off other columns condtiionally on the `NaN` values with `np.where()`

---

```
df['diff'] = np.where(df['col1'].str.extract('([a-z])') == df['col1'].shift(-1).str.extract('([a-z])'),
                      df['col_entity col2'].diff().abs().shift(-1), np.nan)
df['col_statement'] = np.where(df['diff'].isnull(),
                               '**will drop this row**',
                              'difference between' + ' ' + df['col1'] + ' and '
                                   + df['col1'].shift(-1) + ' is ' + df['diff'].astype(str))
df
Out[1]: 
  col1  col_entity col2  diff                         col_statement
a   a1               50  10.0  difference between a1 and a2 is 10.0
b   a2               40  10.0  difference between a2 and a3 is 10.0
a   a3               30  10.0  difference between a3 and a4 is 10.0
a   a4               20   NaN                **will drop this row**
b   b1               40  10.0  difference between b1 and b4 is 10.0
a   b4               50  10.0  difference between b4 and b3 is 10.0
b   b3               30  10.0  difference between b3 and b2 is 10.0
b   b2               20   NaN                **will drop this row**
```